# Power of ICI in OFDM System

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, ofdm

I am studying the effect of time offset in OFDM system, I am interested in calculating the power of the ICI on each subcarrier, I am a bit confused about how to do it in Matlab, so how can I measure the power of ICI on a specific subcarrier in Matlab?

Comment: Do you understand what time offset does to each sub-carrier?

Comment: Yes, so basically I am studying the effect of timing jitter in OFDM systems, I understand it causes both a phase rotation and an ICI, I am interested in measuring the ICI power (on a specific subcarrier) vs. the timing  offset. I could not find a way to measure ICI on a specific subcarrier using Matlab?

Comment: A delay in time is a linear phase in frequency-- so the phase rotation on each subcarrier gets successively larger (does that make sense?). What modulation is your sub-carrier?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am using 4 and 16 QAM. I am aware of the effect of the phase rotation, however I could not find a proper way to measure the ICI on each subcarrier. I tried to to the following: in order to measure the ICI on subcarrier 1 (ICI effect that is caused by all other subcarriers on SC1) I send zero in subcarrier 1 (send nothing) and then the result of fft at the receiver for SC1 should be the ICI. However I did not get resonable results. Any help?

Comment: I'm not providing an answer below as I haven't done this specifically so there may be more direct approaches but I would proceed exactly as you suggested. Can you provide details in your question and why you don't think the results are not reasonable? I also had assumed that CFO was a more dominant source of ICI and still trying to think through how a static timing offset would cause any significant ICI

Comment: The static time offset causes a static phase rotation for each sub-carrier. If a particular sub-carrier is rotated in phase by a static amount, why would that cause any more of it's signal energy to leak to another bin? I am not speaking with any confidence, just thinking it through- do you have a reference that suggests there is ICI and what it should be for a static time offset only?

Comment: Yes you are right, if all SCs face the same offset, then there would not be ICI. But I am studying the case where different SCs face different offsets. Thank you very much. I will add more detials

Comment: ah I see. Yes looking forward to more details. And I don't see any issue with your approach from what you described. The other idea is to send orthogonal codes on each sub-carrier and then you can measure the cross leakage between all sub-carriers simultaneously. But that is a lot more complicated and there is no reason you can't just measure each individually by transmitting in one and turning all other channels off.

Comment: But my last suggestion to use codes wouldn’t apply if the SC have different time delays. How would that actually occur? Group delay variation I assume?

Comment: Ah i see you mentioned timing jitter — for that I suggest analytically approaching that from the power spectral density of the clock’s phase noise and the equivalent filter of the correlation to each subcarrier (FFT bin as a filter) and the the resulting ICI should be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to measure the ICI power on a subcarrier x (ICI that is caused by all other subcarriers). Simply, consider an ideal system without any source of noise, keep all subcarriers turned on (activated) and turn off subcarrier x (through power loading or bit loading) so that subcarrier x does not convey any data. At the receiver, after FFT, the power on subcarrier x is the ICI power. Moreover, the measured EVM (in dB) at subcarrier x is indeed the ICI power in dB.

Comment: did you get the solution how to add the SFO effect into the OFDM ?